# Show an error if the order key is changed manually in URL on Woocommerce thankyou

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, key, orders

I have developed a web page and integrated **Cc Avenue gateway** for payment and it is working fine.

My problem is, after a successful payment from bank customer gets redirected to thank you page which will have details like order no, date, customer details etc. The URL looks something like: `https://mysite/checkout/order-received/785/?key=wc_order_5b909f1966e92`

If I manually change `key=wc_order_5b909f1966e92` to `key=wc_order_5b909f1966e81` it should show error on 'thank you' page like "invalid order". Instead it is showing "Thank you. Your order has been received." without any order details on the page.

Before changing key:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/c68Q8og]

After changing key:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the relevant code somewhere. That might make it easier to help you?

Comment: i am using the functionality of woocommerce with CC avenue payment gate way,i have not written any code for this. My bank gateway has raised this an issue (security threat) when they have done the audit for my we site.please find below feed back from bank " The test found one high-risk vulnerability (i.e. Amount Tampering) open as per the test cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will check order key validity. If the order key doesn't match, it will display a custom error notice *(and optionally redirect to shop page if needed)*:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_thankyou_order_key' );
function check_thankyou_order_key() {
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && isset($_GET['key']) ) {
        global $wp;

        $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
        $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if( $order->get_order_key() != wc_clean($_GET['key']) ){
            // Display a custom error notice
            wc_add_notice( __('Oups! The order key is invalid…', 'woocommerce'), 'error');

            // Optionally redirect to shop page (uncomment code below)
            // wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) );
            // exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> [image]

With the optional redirection to shop page:

> [image]

Comment: thank you so much. exactly what i need, it solved my problem